# How to delete rows that contain special characters in R

Tags: r, string, delete-row, dplyr

`summary(housingdata$City)`

output --->  Amsterdam Amsterdam-Zuidoost            BerlÃ­n

```
         14791                167                  1 
        Berlin     çˆ±ä¸\u0081å ¡  ì—\u0090ë“ ë²„ëŸ¬ 
         13641                  4                  1 
            NA             Others          Stockholm 
             0               8231                692 
          NA's 
            46
```

I tried the following codes, but they don't seem to work:

```
housingdata$City[housingdata$City == 'NA'] <- NA
housingdata$City[housingdata$City == 'çˆ±ä¸\u0081å'] <- NA
housingdata$City[housingdata$City == 'BerlÃn'] <- NA
housingdata$City[housingdata$City == 'ì—\u0090ë“ ë²„ëŸ¬'] <- NA
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean exactly? You seem to be just setting values to NA  (missing) and not attempting to actually delete rows. Do you want the side of your data.frame to shrink? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, I could either try to delete the rows containing those values or set them to NA. In the example above, I tried to set them to NA but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` to  return only letters

```
subset(housingdata, grepl('^[A-Za-z_ -]+$', City))
```

Comment: Since it's in a frame, I recommend `gsub` or `grepl` instead of `grep(..., value=TRUE)`.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner in R. How do I actually use the solution above for my problem? I tried the following: subset(housingdata, grepl('^[BerlÃn]+$', City)) and that doesn't seem to produce the output that I want. I would expect to delete the rows with unreadable characters or change the values to NA. And if I just copy the code above, the following message appears: "Error in grepl("^[A-Za-z_- ]+$", City) : 
  invalid regular expression '^[A-Za-z_- ]+$', reason 'Invalid character range'" @r2evans

Comment: @TonyFlager you are not usiing the same pattern in my post.  Your pattern seems to be using `Ã` to check for those characters

Comment: @TonyFlager can you try the pattern now in the updated post

Comment: Ã–stermalm              Amsterdam 
                     0                  14792 
    Amsterdam-Zuidoost           Badhoevedorp 
                   167                      1 
             BANDHAGEN                BerlÃ­n 
                     1                      0 
                Berlin            BjÃ¶rkhagen 
                 13640                      0 
Bruntsfield, Edinburgh         çˆ±ä¸\u0081å ¡ 
                     0                      0 
          Ð‘ÐµÑ€Ð»Ð¸Ð½ Ð\u0090Ð¼Ñ\u0081Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð´Ð°Ð¼ 
                     0                      0

Comment: The code works and seems to filter the observations out, but when I code "summary(cleanhousingdata$City)", I can still see those 0 observations. How do I remove them so that they don't turn up anymore?

Comment: @TonyFlager You can use `summary(droplevels(cleanhousingdata$City))`